# How can i send an ephemeral message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-interactions

I want a bot to respond with an ephemeral message to a custom command called `/help` in discord.py. So that when i send `/help` in my discord server, the message that the user sent gets removed and the bot responds with an ephemeral message.

I have tried to use ctx and discord.InteractionResponse instead of discord.Interaction but it will just return with an error, like:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'response'`.

And here is the code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'my_token'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

help_text = 'This is a help text'

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is now up and running.")

bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.command()
    async def help(ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1) # Remove the user message
        # await ctx.send(help_text)
        
        # interaction = discord.InteractionResponse
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hello", ephemeral=True) # Should send a ephemeral message

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a normal commands rather than an interaction. You can think of interaction based stuff as predefined commands you notify discord about. Whenever a new command is created, you have to sync it.

Calling purge on a channel to remove one message isn't a good idea. If anyone sends a message between the command and response, it might end up deleting the normal message instead.

[image: Command result example]

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree=app_commands.CommandTree(bot)

@tree.command(name="help", description="A basic help command.")
async def help(interaction):
    #  Since now we have interaction we can send the message as an ephemeral message.
    #  We also dont have to deal with deleting the command message.
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Help command.", ephemeral=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Sync commands on command tree with discord.
    await tree.sync()
    print(f"{bot.user} is now up and running.")
    
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent like almost an hour to find code that worked but your code worked. Also do you happen to know how to add arguments to that command, like: `/help about:”bot”` or `about:”server”`?

Comment: Thats definitely doable. Easiest way to do it is to add a positional or keyword argument. If you want to show the choices that you accept or autocomplete them. I would recommend looking at the documentation from [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#data-classes) as its a bit out of scope to write about in a comment.